# Creating a DataFrame in Pandas for a two columns and single data row

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to Pandas and DataFrame concept and learning through experiments. While creating a new DataFrame I tried with the following code, but gives me some error. Please suggest.

```
import pandas as pd

akshit = pd.DataFrame({'Name': 'Akshit', 'Last': 'Gupta'})
```

I expected the dataframe to be created, but I am getting the following error:

> ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Name is the column name and should get an array of data. This is why you have to use brackets for the columns:

```
akshit = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Akshit'], 'Last': ['Gupta']})
akshit

Out[7]: 
     Name   Last
0  Akshit  Gupta
```

Answer (score 2):

As the suggestion says, you can pass an `index` like:

```
akshit = pd.DataFrame({'Name': 'Akshit', 'Last': 'Gupta'}, index=[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error message mentions, since your dict values are scalers, the index can't be auto-inferred and must be mentioned explicitely. SO this will work

```
akshit = pd.DataFrame({'Name': 'Akshit', 'Last': 'Gupta'}, index = [0])
```

Obviously, you can extend it to multiple rows

```
names = pd.DataFrame([{'Name': 'Akshit', 'Last': 'Gupta'},
                      {'Name': 'Neel', 'Last': 'Ray'} , index = [0,1])
```

Alternately, You can mention the values of your dict as lists, so that the index can be inferred by the position of elements in the lists.

```
alshit = pd.DataFrame([{'Name': ['Akshit'], 'Last': ['Gupta']})
```